# HTML editing: Alternative of entering "&lt;" and "&gt;"

Tags: html, editor, blogger

When editing an HTML file with source code, I sometimes met this problem:

E.g.

```
<p>C uses statement <pre>include <stdio.h></pre> to include a library</p>
```

I have to manually change the `<stdio.h>` into `&lt;stdio.h&lt;` to make it display normally.

Considering work with this mixed situation frequently, this manual changing consumes much time.

Is there any good solution to it?

Comment: If you are writing this out by hand, no. If you're not, you should be able to use some sort of HTML encode on your string before you output (It's not clear from your question whether this snippet is being created programmatically or not)

Answer (score 2):

You need not change the greater than sign “>”. It is often escaped, but this is just a habit and serves symmetry, in many people’s opinion. But only the less than sign “<” *needs* to be escaped.

If it is too much work, consider using e.g. an editor where you copy and paste the code to be inserted and run a global replace, replacing “<” by `&lt;` *and* “&” by `&amp;`.

The only way to avoid the escaping in HTML would be to use the `xmp` element, e.g. `<p>C uses statement <xmp>include <stdio.h></xmp> to include a library</p>`. However, `xmp` is nonstandard (though universally supported) and rendered as a block by default and, worst of all here, parsed as a block element, i.e. the `<xml>` tag implicitly closes the open `p` element, and this affects rendering of course. So `xmp` isn’t that practical for *inline* code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the text editors, even `Notepad` comes with a *Find and Replace* option, paste your code in there, and use the *Find and Replace* option to change all the `<` into `&lt;` and `>` into `&gt;`

Answer (score -1):

There are several options you could consider

**Javascript**
Use javascript to do something like:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("code");
//get the innerHTML and change < to &lt; and > to &gt;
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/\</g,"&lt;").replace(/\>/g,"&gt;");
```

This will look for an elment with class "code" read it's input and change it to the appropriate form.

**PHP or other server side language**
In PHP you could use htmlspecialchars(). You could read out a file in PHP and use htmlspecialchars on it (there probably are thousands of tutorials on how to do this online)

**Use a bash (or whatever script)**
with sed you could use:

```
sed -e 's/\</\&#60;/g' -e 's/\>/\&#62;/g' filename.c > newfile.html
```

this will take the file you gave it (filename.c) and change al the < and > to the appropriate things and store the output in newfile.html . Now you can just coppypaste the content off newfile.

**Toughts**
If this is for a website I advice you to encode the text on the server side (using the PHP thing). If it is for a static site, it might be more usefull to use sed. And if it is only for a few chars per webpage, I advice you to do it manually. (or use a WYSIWYG editor)

Comment: If using sed or similar, you have to be more careful to NOT change the angle brackets used for actual HTML markup, and only the ones inside pre tags. The javascript solution would work since it's more selective in what it transforms. Any serverside templating framework should have a way to designate pieces of text that should be handled that way, whethere PHP, Rails, or something else.

Comment: The JavaScript approach means that the HTML document is invalid and the script code tries to make it valid; this fails because the invalid markup has already caused wrong parsing, hence wrong DOM.